# Manga about the blind descendant of a hero who learns water magic in order to see

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga

It's new, as it only has a few chapters so far. It is about the descendant of a hero who is blind, but he has to marry a princess and he learns water magic and they find out he is a prodigy. They later find out that his goal is to use water magic to see. It's very interesting and I hope someone knows the title.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, do you recall anything about the cover, such as the hair colour of the main character or the princess?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure this is ***[Kunon the Sorcerer Can See Through](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/ujuslxg/majutsushi-kunon-wa-miete-iru)***.

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/majutsushi-kunon-wa-mieteiru):

> Sometimes all it takes is one word to change your whole life. Kunon Gurion was born blinded by the curse known as the “Hero’s Scar.” Unable to see, or even see the meaning of life, he spent his childhood in apathy. Then one day, a water emblem appears on his body, and it turns out he is capable of magic. So what? Regardless of whether he has magical power or able to use magic, the fact remains that he cannot see. Kunon was still unable to see the meaning of life. Though an unexpected comment that was not intended to be such awakened Kunon.

This is a new manga, first published in 2022.

In the world the story is set in, there's a phenomenon known as the 'Hero's Scar' which causes certain descendants of heroes to be missing something when they're born, such as a body part, their emotions, or their sense of taste.

In the case of Kunon Gurion, the son of a noble, he was born unable to see. Some time during his childhood, though, a water crest manifests on his shoulder, signifying that he can use water magic, and he's given a tutor shortly afterwards. Kunon practices making water balls, and hopes that one day he can use sorcery to make an eye to see with.

Another prominent character in the story is Mirika Hyuuglia, the ninth princess of the Hyuuglia Kingdom, who became engaged to Kunon around the time that his magic awakened.

As the story progresses, Kunon acquires the ability to distinguish between different colours and to read, although he still lacks normal vision, and relies on physical contact to perceive things more clearly.

[image]

[image]